# Project name is invalid while creating the project with ng new command

Tags: angular

I am installed the latest version of angular-cli on my local and trying to create a new project using the command ng new ETG.WEB.UI --style=scss.

I am getting error message Project name ETG.WEB.UI is invalid. It runs successfully if I use command ng new ETG --style=scss

Could somebody tell me if it is genuinely not as per angular-cli permit table naming conventions OR do i simply rename the project from ETG to ETG.WEB.UI once it is created.

Comment: Consider using dashes rather than dots in the application name. Since the CLI uses JSON for all configuration, dot notation can play havoc.

Answer (score 14):

Create a new project using a hyphen as the separator then rename the folder it creates.

```
ng new ETG-WEB-UI --style=scss
```

This will create a folder named ETG-WEB-UI. Simply rename it to ETG.WEB.UI either in the command prompt or in Windows.

Then run ng serve as normal:

```
ng serve
```

I've just tried this and so far I haven't had any issues with the project after renaming it.

Comment: Did the same, worked flawlessly. Just to be sure i changed the project info here and there in all .json files (angular.json, package.json exc...)

Comment: In the angular.json file you can't have a dot in your `projects` > `<projectname here>`. You can solve this by having a dash instead, but make sure to put the dash in your `projects` > `ETG-WEB-UI` > `architect` > `serve` > .. > `browserTarget`

Answer (score 6):

What you can also do is change `ng new` command a bit to include the directory name as well. Here the project name is `ETGWebUI` and directory name is `ETG.WEB.UI`

```
ng new ETGWebUI --directory ETG.WEB.UI
```

*Sometimes the dashes (-) in projects name produces the error as well.* So I would recommend not to use dashes too. But you can do anything to directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Try without dot "."
E.g.
ETG-WEB-UI

I had the same problem and I replaced . for - and worked for me.